# How do I remove the right arrow from the URL bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

The new Firefox URL bar has a right arrow that appears after someone begins typing text in there. I know that you can get rid of the Pocket logo and the Favorite logo by right clicking and selecting remove from address bar.

Is it possible to remove the right arrow from an active URL bar?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your FF version, so I will spend some time to tell you how to find the sourcecode of that right arrow.

1. Follow this tutorial [Tutorial: How to create and live-debug userChrome.css](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/73dvty/tutorial_how_to_create_and_livedebug_userchromecss/) to enable two developer options: "Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes" and "Enable remote debugging".
2. I assume you have already opened *Browser Toolbox*. Then you can use the left above icon which should generate a popup "Pick an element from the page(Ctrl+Shift+C)" when hovering on it.
3. Use that tool to inspect the right arrow. You may find

```
<xul:image class="urlbar-go-button urlbar-icon" anonid="urlbar-go-button" onclick="gURLBar.handleCommand(event);" tooltiptext="Go to the address in the Location Bar" xbl:inherits="pageproxystate,parentfocused=focused,usertyping" pageproxystate="valid"/>
```

Then you can remove the class `urlbar-go-button` and check if the right arrow still exists.

If it doesn't exist, it means you find the right element. Then add the following style to your userChrome.css to permanently disable it.

```css
.urlbar-go-button {
  list-style-image: none;
}
```